# How to handle return from recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to make a polyomino generator of level N. I successfully made a function that connects a tile with a root in every possible way and returns all combinations. Now I need to extend this to level N. I've done my best, but still can't handle recursion the right way.
Here's my function:

```
def connect_n(tiles,root,n=1):
    if not isinstance(tiles[0], list): tiles = [tiles]
    result = []
    if n == 1:
        for tile in tiles:
            result += connect(tile, root)
        return result
    else:
        return connect_n(tiles, root,n-1)
```

This function successfully creates N nested functions and executes *base case* at `n==1`. But then with obtained result, it just goes up and up and exits with that result without any other iterations. I'm sure I'm missing something. I tried to move conditions and loops around without success.

I have following input:

```
root = (0,0)
N = 3 #for example, can be any number > 0
```

Function `connect(root,root)` returns:

```
[[(0, 0), (1, 0)]]
```

Then function`connect([[(0, 0), (1, 0)]],root)` returns

```
[[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0)], 
 [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0)], 
 [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)], 
 [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1)]]
```

And so on.

Function `connect_n` output should be

```
[[(0, 0), (1, 0)]] for N=1
```

```
[[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0)],
 [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0)],
 [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)],
 [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1)]]  for N=2
```

And so on.

Comment: You need to combine an intermediate result with the result from the recursive call. Like the way factorial multiplies the current number with the result of the recursion.

Comment: Can you add sample data and the desired result?

Comment: @Barmar added samples

Comment: You have no samples of `connect_n()`, only `connect()`.

Comment: @Barmar  `connect_n`  output should be `[[(0, 0), (1, 0)]]` for N=1, `[[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0)],  [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0)],  [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)],  [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1)]]` for N=2 and so on.

Comment: Put that in the question, not a comment.

Comment: @Barmar added. Sorry I'm new here.

Comment: I don't see the difference between what `connect()` and `connect_n()` return.

Comment: @Barmar cause it is same. Difference is N. `connect_n()` must iterate with results from N-1 level until level N.

Comment: What are the `tiles` and `root` arguments to `connect_n()`?

Comment: @Barmar `tiles` are the N-1 result and `root` is always same in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the algorithm, but I think this is what you want:

```
def connect_n(tiles, root, n=1):
    if n == 1:
        return connect(tiles, root)
    else:
        return connect_n(connect_n(tiles, root, n-1)), root)
```

Comment: Function `connect` take only single `tile` at a time. It can't take all `tiles`. That's why there are loop in `N==1`

Comment: Replacing last line with `return connect_n(connect_n(tiles, root, n-1)), root)` worked for me. Thank you.